# How do I terminate a socket server in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I wrote a webserver with, say, the webserver package, and can start it in ghci with:

```
:main localhost 8000
```

If I <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> it and run that again, I get

```
*** Exception: bind: resource busy (Address already in use)
```

So the socket seems to be bound to my ghci session.

How can I free that port binding so that I can `:reload` and start it again without quitting ghci?

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens if the underlying server implementation does not set the [`REUSE_ADDR`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.4.0.1/doc/html/Network-Socket.html#v%3aReuseAddr) option on the socket.

Usually if you terminate a server abruptly, the operating system keeps that server's old port in the 2MSL state for a couple of minutes in order to prevent new servers on that port from accidentally receiving old messages intended for the previous connection.  If you set `REUSE_ADDR` when attempting to bind the port, you specify that you wish to forcefully reuse it before the 2MSL period is over.

The only way you can fix this is to modify the code for the underlying web server that you are using to set the `REUSE_ADDR` option before binding the listening socket.

Comment: I don't thinnk `REUSE_ADDR` is the problem - the socket immediately becomes free once I quit ghci. My problem is that I need this to happen on the `Ctrl-C` that terminates main.

Comment: @nh2 In that case I'm not sure.  I thought `:reload` would be the way to reset `ghci` and free all resources, but you already said that doesn't work.

Comment: `ghci` has no way of knowing the socket is even open. Your server will need to trap signals, catch `SIGINT` (amongst others), and close the socket when it gets that signal.  And yes, you'll still need the `REUSE_ADDR` option, though it sounds like that is being set.

Comment: @MtnViewMark So what exactly happens when I press Ctrl-C in `:main`? I had expected ghci forking itself and creating a subprocess which whom the port binding would die once I kill it.

Comment: `:main` doesn't fork. It just sets up things so `getArgs` will see the strings passed on the `:main` line. (See `System.Environment.withArgs`.) When you press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> ghci catches it, and returns to the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Linux? If yes, I think that you have to use `lsof` to find out which process is using a given port, then just kill the PID. I already had a problem like that with Flask in Python, so I think that it is the same thing here. You leave ghci open, kill the process and then reload ghci. It is not an elegant method, but if it work, it is good!

Comment: Nice idea, but that kills my whole ghci.